# Send Push Notification with Firebase from one the device to another

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am programming a iOS and Android app with Firebase. Now I want to implement Push Notifications. That works fine so far. I want that when a user interacts with another in a certain action one user is getting notified via a push notification.

Now my question is how can I achieve this, I am saving the FCM token in my users collections. I thought I could use the FCM API but then I need the Bearer token can I save something like this in the app or do I need to write my own backend for this?

And thoughts on this, maybe I am missing something. I know there are Cloud Functions but I can't use them because then the project needed to be a Blaze project. The problem is, that I don't want surprise bills from firebase since this is a hobby project.

Comment: You need to write your own backend in which you'll save the FCM token with user details i.e Phone Number , email, password etc, table schema is totally upto you. And then when a user wants to send a notification to another user he'll send the notification using his FCM token. Hope this clears your concept.

Comment: But I already use Firestore to save my data I just need to send push notifications, or do you see a good way to have a overview about firebase pricing because I am afraid of surprise bills.